# Can Go be reasonably implemented on the .net framework?

Tags: .net, go

Given that the .net framework was designed to support languages of all flavors, can Go be implemented with full fidelity on it? While both are managed, there seem to be many unique aspects to Go compared to the languages currently supported by .net, including:

1. Go's automatic management of stack vs heap variables.
2. Channels
3. Packages as an intrinsic part of Go
4. Go's concurrency vs .net's Async/await
5. Go's ABI

Do any of these (or any other factors) prevent a full-featured Go from being written on top of the .net framework?

This question is to help me understand of the differences between Go and the .net framework at the most basic levels.

Comment: Regarding concurrency, no, there's nothing preventing that. Go concurrency is a subset of .NET concurrency.

Comment: 0) The claim ".net framework was designed to support languages of all flavors" is a very bold one, and should be taken with several ounces of salt. First of all, .NET 1.0 was merely created to displace Java on Windows Desktop where MS has problems interacting with Sun back then. Hence .NET has certain birth traumas which stem directly from this initial goal. Actually if you'll look at C# 2.0 you'll see it also dutifully implements most of Java warts. Hence .NET was created to support OO-languages based on Java-like ideas.

Comment: 1) Yes; 2) Yes but see #4; 3) Probably yes; 4) That one is hard to answer definitely. The chief difference in concurrency between .NET and Go is very well explained [here](http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/). Go has support for concurrency in its runtime by having separate stacks for its goroutines and the scheduler which kicks in completely transparently to the goroutine at certain key point of its execution--naturally when it's about to stall on an I/O operation. Conversely, `async/await` of .NET involve splitting of functions at each `await` they do.

Comment: So yes, it should definitely be possible to utilize the .NET core to simulate the behaviour of the Go runtime but these worlds are different enough, so only simulation is possible--not sort of direct mapping of concepts. 5) I think this one is next to impossible to achieve. First, I doubt this concept exist in Go "as is"--up until v1.7 I would say: Go probrams built by its reference tool stack are static, and libraries were AFAIK explicitly not designed as being "shippable": you were supposed to (re)build them as needed from the source code. Go 1.7 introduced support for "shippable" libraries

Comment: on certain platforms, and Go 1.8 will have certain support for "plugin-style" libraries which can be dynamically loaded. This all definitely makes the idea of ABI existing but the next roadblock in implementing it would be the fact Go is compiled down to machine level--not to some sort of IL like .NET does. Hence there is a distinct ABI for each supported H/W architecture (and supposedly also Go version), and it's defined in terms of calling conventions involving CPU registers and all that. I'm afraid implementing this would require working through the interop level of .NET (P/Invoke),

Comment: and I'm afraid that one might make broad assumptions about what it can call (and what it's able to export)--as .NET's P/Invoke was IMO primarily designed to introperate with libraries written in C, C++, Pascal et all with the support of several "well-known in x86" calling conventions. Dunno whether it will be able to cut what Go uses as ABI.

Comment: All-in-all, I don't really see a point in making Go available on .NET except for its nice syntax. If we forget about interop and assume all the Go-native libraries we'd like to use are available with its source code and can be compiled with that imaginary Go.NET compiler, that could possibly work if there would be a reasonably seamless way to call .NET libs from such Go programs. This one is the most interesting topic but it's absolutely not fit for SO. I'd hence recommend bring this question up on the [Go mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts) ;-)

Comment: @kostix, Thanks. There's a very good reason for running Go (or any other language) on .net - code reuse in both directions. It enables Go apps to reuse the vast ecosystem of .net libraries, and vice versa. It also permits .net apps an eventual migration path to Go that does not require everything to be rewritten overnight. That's much more than nice syntax, although syntax is a good reason for choosing Go in the first place.

Comment: I'm afraid you might be missing one "devops" point here:people writing in Go usually value its ease of deployment. Sure .NET also touts "xcopy deployment" but it implies .NET of a required version is installed on the target machine. This might be perfectly sensible in Windows world but much less so in other OS domains where .NET core and related technologies "are not there yet". And there is the question of performance (expectations when moving from "native" to "hosted" Go) and tooling etc. Gradual rewrites are another thing; I tend to agree on this point.

Comment: Go interop with .NET is not possible without breaking Go's concurrency model. It *depends* on things like synchronization primitives and OS threads *not* being available.

Comment: @StephenCleary, are you referring to "shoot yourself in the foot" scenarios? Misuse of Go pointers is already in that category, so that isn't necessarily a blocker, do you agree?

Comment: @bright: No, I mean that Go's concurrency model only works if it's the *only* concurrency model. It would fall apart if you tried to combine it with another concurrency model.

Comment: @StephenCleary, is that really so? As an extreme case, a Go process coexists with other processes in the OS, so one could visualize a process barrier between the rest of .net and Go. I'm not saying that's the way to go, but it's a starting point in thinking about the isolation Go types need from other code running in the CLR, and whether CLR changes are needed or whether the Go semantics can be represented with the existing opcodes.

Comment: @bright: What I'm saying is that you can't, e.g., have a thread in the Go world lock on a Win32 OS Mutex. It would prevent Go's concurrency from working. Thus, a Go system would have to be in its own world, without .NET interop (direct calls). They'd have to be made into remote non-blocking calls.